# login system without cookies using variables

Tags: python, google-app-engine

In some video courses I saw that the author uses cookies to make a login system. I wonder isn’t it possible to make it without cookies, since the cookies might be disabled in the user’s browser. I think it is a good way to store the values in variables then assign them user options. Can someone recommend me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally tokens are used as an alternative to cookies ([JSON web tokens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token)), there are multiple resources for example [cookies vs tokens](https://auth0.com/blog/cookies-vs-tokens-definitive-guide/).

[image]

But also could be of your interest to check the OSWAP [Authentication Cheat Sheety](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Can't just be used global variables on the server side?

Comment: @HaykArabyan I don't know if, with global variables you mean server side sessions, this normally match the client via cookie, or you can go more basic and just use [Basic access authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)

Comment: I mean exactly global variables on the server side.

Comment: For example logged_info  = True

Comment: You can use any logic you prefer, but for example, if you have N+1 users how are you going to distinguish go is logged and who is not? this is why you need either cookies or tokens to identify your clients, that was the origin of your question